# Change XML node name dynamically to cycle through long list in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

You guys were a great help last time and I'm becoming more comfortable with XML in SQL Server but still very much a novice.

My latest challenge is I have nodes that are named the same, like up to 50 times and only a number differentiates them:

```
<QuoteHeaderXML>
  <QuoteHeaderData>
    <QuoteHeader>
      <Configurable01 Value="" Name="Credit Memo" />
      <Configurable02 Value="" Name="Contact Person" />
      <Configurable04 Value="N/A" Name="Fed Ex Rated" />
      <Configurable05 Value="Not Branded" Name="Branding" />
      <Configurable06 Value="100%" Name="Project Status" />
      <Configurable07 Value="" Name="Project Name" />
      <Configurable08 Value="None" Name="Project Manager" />
      <Configurable09 Value="" Name="Shipping Notes" />
      <Configurable10 Value="False" Name="High Profile Order" />
      <Configurable11 Value="New Construction" Name="Project Type" />
      <Configurable12 Value="Single-family" Name="Channel" />
      <Configurable13 Value="US - Texas - Northern" Name="Job Location" />
      <Configurable20 Value="Dealer Warehouse" Name="Delivery Destination" />
    </QuoteHeader>
  </QuoteHeaderData>
</QuoteHeaderXML>
```

So if I want to pull columns for ConfigurableNN, Name and Value,  I'd have to write this 50x to pull all of them into individual rows where they exist... or call out each for each of the 50 ending up in 150+ columns table!  I don't like these options.

Instead, I'm looking to write the code to pull ConfigurableNN, Name and Value once, but have it dynamically change the number of the node based on a counter.  However, I can't see to do this as it complains *"The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.".*

This is what I tried and futzed with from posts I found but can't make work... any suggestions or is this just not possible?

```
WHILE @ConfigCounter <= 50
    BEGIN
        SET @CfgNum = case when @ConfigCounter < 10 then '0' else '' end + cast(@ConfigCounter as varchar(2));

        select t.x.value('(Configurable'+cast(@CfgNum as varchar(2))+'/@Name)[1]','varchar(255)')   ConfigurableFieldName
              ,t.x.value('(Configurable'+cast(@CfgNum as varchar(2))+'/@Value)[1]','varchar(255)')  ConfigurableFieldValue
          from @XMLData.nodes('//QuoteHeaderXML/QuoteHeaderData/QuoteHeader') as T(X)
         where t.x.value('(Configurable'+cast(@CfgNum as varchar(2))+'/@Value)[1]','varchar(255)') is not null      

        SET @ConfigCounter = @ConfigCounter + 1; 
    END
```

Thanks in advance for the help, tips and/or ideas!  =)

Comment: The part within XML's `.value()` must be a literal. Your approach would work with dynamically created statements and `EXEC`, but this is pure procedural thinking and not necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this XML is under your control you should change this. It is a very bad design, to separate the same elements with a running number as a part of the element's name. If you need this number, you might add it as an attribute like

```
<Configurable Nr="01" Value="" Name="Credit Memo" />
```

You do not need it necessarily, as the element's order within am XML is guaranteed (not the attribute's order though), but It makes some queries easier.

If you have to stick with this, you can use the Asterisk `*` to get all nodes below `<QuoteHeader>` in one go:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<QuoteHeaderXML>
  <QuoteHeaderData>
    <QuoteHeader>
      <Configurable01 Value="" Name="Credit Memo" />
      <Configurable02 Value="" Name="Contact Person" />
      <Configurable04 Value="N/A" Name="Fed Ex Rated" />
      <Configurable05 Value="Not Branded" Name="Branding" />
      <Configurable06 Value="100%" Name="Project Status" />
      <Configurable07 Value="" Name="Project Name" />
      <Configurable08 Value="None" Name="Project Manager" />
      <Configurable09 Value="" Name="Shipping Notes" />
      <Configurable10 Value="False" Name="High Profile Order" />
      <Configurable11 Value="New Construction" Name="Project Type" />
      <Configurable12 Value="Single-family" Name="Channel" />
      <Configurable13 Value="US - Texas - Northern" Name="Job Location" />
      <Configurable20 Value="Dealer Warehouse" Name="Delivery Destination" />
    </QuoteHeader>
  </QuoteHeaderData>
</QuoteHeaderXML>';

SELECT ConfigurableX.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,ConfigurableX.value(N'@Value',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Value
      ,ConfigurableX.value(N'@Name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Name
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/QuoteHeaderXML/QuoteHeaderData/QuoteHeader/*') AS GetAllBelowQuoteHeader(ConfigurableX);
```

The result

```
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| NodeName       | Value                 | Name                 |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable01 |                       | Credit Memo          |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable02 |                       | Contact Person       |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable04 | N/A                   | Fed Ex Rated         |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable05 | Not Branded           | Branding             |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable06 | 100%                  | Project Status       |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable07 |                       | Project Name         |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable08 | None                  | Project Manager      |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable09 |                       | Shipping Notes       |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable10 | False                 | High Profile Order   |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable11 | New Construction      | Project Type         |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable12 | Single-family         | Channel              |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable13 | US - Texas - Northern | Job Location         |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Configurable20 | Dealer Warehouse      | Delivery Destination |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately that XML design is from the vendor of our application... and it's not the only poor design item.  Thanks a bunch, that worked like a champ.  I added the following as there are actually other fields beyond the Configurables, although I only gave those in the example so as not to confuse.  I added:   WHERE left(ConfigurableX.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)'),12) = 'Configurable';

Comment: @AKenn, That is okay, but I'd prefer to place the filter within `XQuery`. Change the `.nodes()` by adding a predicate to the `*`: `*[substring(local-name(),1,12)="Configurable"]` This means: *All elements, as long as the first 12 characters of their name is "Configurable"* This makes no big deal with small sets, but can bring quite some performance in larger queries.